# Connection between Twitter status and Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter

I'm trying to bring my latest status from Twitter to my Rails app. I have the config details stored in an initialiser and have it displaying my latest tweet, but I want to also bring the date of this tweet. I have the following code and not sure whether to try and amend it or start again.

**initializers.twitter.rb**

```
module TwitterStatus
 $client = Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
  config.consumer_key        = "##hidden##"
  config.consumer_secret     = "##hidden##"
  config.access_token        = "##hidden##"
  config.access_token_secret = "##hidden##"
 end

 def user_timeline(qt)
  $client.user_timeline(count: qt)
 end

end
```

**controllers/application_contorller.rb**

```
include TwitterStatus

def index
 @tweets = user_timeline(1)
end
```

main/index.html.erb

```
<% @tweets.each do |tweet| %>
  <p><%= link_to tweet.text, "https://www.twitter.com/#{tweet.user.screen_name}" %></p>
<% end %>
```

Any help would be appreciated, ideally, I'd like to be able to pull all the tweet info (img, name, etc...) and just use what I need.

Comment: Seems `@tweets` has the info you need already. Have you checked what it holds exactly?

Comment: Hi Mischa, I'm not sure what I would do to find what it holds. Can you provide more info?

Comment: You can add the following after you have set `@tweets` in the index method: `logger.debug @tweets.inspect` and then check your log file to see what `@tweets` holds.

Comment: Another option would be to look at the documentation for the Twitter client you're using.

Comment: When trying to raise and inspect @tweets, I only get the tweet Id. I've looked through the client documentation and it seems a bit high level for me, so i'm trying to work through it bit by bit.

Comment: Instead of inspecting `@tweets`, try inspecting the first tweet, like this: `raise @tweets.first.inspect`.

Comment: That seems to still only bring the tweet ID :(

Comment: That's strange. What do you get when you try the following: `raise @tweets.first.to_yaml`

Comment: That brings all the information such as 'screen_name', 'created_at'! Thank you so much. I can then simply call <%= tweet.created_at %> etc.. to show any info I need, Excellent!

Answer (score 0):

Answer provided by [Mischa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/84631/mischa)

*To view the tweet attributes*

> 

Then use the attributes as follows

> <%= tweet.created_at %> etc